# Is it possible to build a binary divider with this design?

Tags: logic-gates, binary, arithmetic-division, computer-arithmetic

So I am working on this ALU, and I have made this 8-bit multiplier based on this design: [image: multiplier design]. Is it possible to adapt this design into a binary divider by using Subtractors instead of Adders, and maybe add some logic gates or do I need to start from scratch on the division unit?

Comment: Do you know how to divide? Yes? It's totally different from multiplying, right? You can't just multiply but subtract instead of adding?

Comment: Technically you can do subtraction until you can no longer subtract anymore and count how many times you subtracted to find out how many times number A fits in number B. Or is it addition? My math teacher showed me somehow to use either addition or subtraction to divide a number, can't remember how though.

Comment: Look at section **2.2.7** in the [ADSP-2111 User's Manual](http://www.bitsavers.org/components/analogDevices/dsp/ADSP-2111_Users_Manual_Architecture_Mar90.pdf). You will see how to use an ALU to perform division. You should also look up Wallace trees for your multiplier. You will use the same number of full and half adders, but the propagation delay will be less with the Wallace arrangement.

Comment: @JamieEngel You could make a circuit that subtracts until it can no longer subtract any more. You could also do long division but in binary. That way is better.

Comment: okay, I will look at the Wallace tree approach, and binary long division. Thanks!

Comment: @JamieEngel It's worth the time to learn about Wallace trees and to study how others have achieved division. The ADSP-21xx has a very interesting and quite useful implementation. And their documentation is almost sufficient for someone relatively familiar with basic ideas. If you have questions about their implementation, feel free to ask.